# ListView doesn't see binding object properties

Tags: c#, xaml, listview

I have a trouble with displaying properties of instance of external class. There is `ListView` markup:

```
<ListView
x:Name="transportListView"
SelectionMode="None"
ItemsSource="{Binding MyModel}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Padding="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10" Background="Gray">
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding ItemName}"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding ItemCount}"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

`MyModel` is the page property:

```
...
    public ObservableCollection<ExternalClass> MyModel { get; set; }
...
```

`ExternalClass` is the class in some referenced library:

```
namespace Library.Entities
{
    public class ExternalClass
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int ItemCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So when I run my application I see list items because I set grey color, but `ItemName` and `ItemCount` is not displaying, why? I adding items to collection correctly and binding works for internal classes perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `ListView`'s `ItemsSource` to `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`. Like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="transportListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  ....
```

Also in the code behind add `this.DataContext = MyModel;` below the `InitializeComponent();`:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = MyModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Use ListView you also need to Define View (GridView) for it:

```html
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyModel}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Count" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemCount}"  />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

If you want to define template for each row then you can use a ListBox instead of ListView:

```html
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyModel}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Padding="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10" Background="Gray">
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: I changed markup to use listbox, but TextBlocks are empty whatever

Comment: Do you see gray background for each item? Try setting Foreground="Black" for TextBlocks.

Comment: FYI, I don't think having the Model in a referenced library is a problem. I tried that and I can still see the results. So most probably there is problem in xaml formatting.